# Zooming with UITextView and Content Size

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

This question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537861/uitextview-with-zooming), but hopefully it will pick up some more interest due to me having tried some stuff.

I am trying to do standard pinch-pan scrolling in a UITextView. My delegate implements `UITextViewDelegate` and implements this method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self;
}
```

[which may in fact be wrong, but returning `[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0]` didn't change anything (strangely).

so the pinching stuff works, but when there is a zoom, the UITextView instance loses all notion of allowing me to pan around the content correctly. I've tried to remedy this by including this method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    CGSize size = self.contentSize;
    size.width *= scale;
    size.height *= scale;
    self.contentSize = size;
}
```

but all of this guesswork has not gotten me very far (not surprisingly).

**Edit:** I've done a thing like this, and aside from it blowing up after a bit, it's not exactly what I want. It's the `action` method of a `UIPincheGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void) doSomething:(id)sender {
    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
    float size = 12 * factor;
    if (size > 6 && size < 40) {
        self.font = [[UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:12 * factor] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this will add a lot of coherence to the zoom. You could also adjust the text width, which I'm going to look into now:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view {
    frameBeforeZooming = self.frame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    self.frame = frameBeforeZooming;
}
```

obviously you need a CGRect defined in the header.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I had trouble with it recently so hopefully this helps someone:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      for(UIView *subView in self.subviews)
      {
         if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIWebDocumentView class]])
            return subView;
      }
      return [self.subviews lastObject];
}
```

Comment: looks good +1, I will have to check it out at some point and accept this answer if it's right. Thanks!