# How to zoom in and zoom out inside the text view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextview with zooming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537861/uitextview-with-zooming)

Is there any zoom in and zoom out option in UITextview.if I tap the text view I want the text to zoom.

Help me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in zooming UITextView, when you can increase the font size on UITextView delegate.

```
UITextView *textView = [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeFontSize:)];
[textView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

- (void)changeFontSize:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    float yourFontSize = gestureRecognizer.scale * FONT_SIZE;
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize];
}
```